# Tracking Computer Lab Logins

Tags: active-directory

My department is in charge of several computer labs, and we'd like to track how many times someone logs into each computer.

Users log in via Active Directory accounts. I've seen some indication that I can track the last login with Active Directory, but not keep a count of total logins. Does anybody know a way to do this in Active Directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, at $previous_employer we ended up using a third party product to do this.  Partly because we were the last people on earth to move to Active Directory ;) and we bought the product before we got AD, but afterwards we looked at getting rid of the third party product and it provided functionality we couldn't get without it--namely, the reports that the lab supervisors used to justify the number of lab assistants on duty and the hours they stayed open.

You might be able to roll your own with some kind of login scripts, but it would probably be easier to go with a third party solution.  We used Pharos SignUp, but there are competitors.  (Most will authenticate off AD.)  They have other cool features, like print management and machine reservations and such, but the reports were what kept us.

Comment: Yup. AD natively does not track this. You can collect login events from workstations or DCs, or hook in something in your login scripts, or buy a product that does one/both of those things for you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. We don't have a budget for this, so I'll have to keep looking at free solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It is scriptable if you have no budget.

Powershell script to pull logon info from event logs:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Find-user-logon-duration-667b8c48

Or very quick and dirty use logon and logoff scripts to write to a pile of text log files on a network share and then gather the data from there:

```
REM Logoff Script:
echo %username% logged OFF %computername% @ %time% %date% >> \\servername\sharename$\%username%.txt 


REM Startup Script:
for /f "Tokens=2 Delims=[]" %%i in ('ping -n 1 "%computername%"') do set IP=%%i
echo Started up, IP=%IP% @ %time% %date% >> \\servername\computers$\%computername%.txt
```

From: http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/70-track-login-and-logout